# Four processes of 1gb,1.2gb,2gb,2gb are there and RAM available is 2gb. We have a time shared system.

Tags: operating-system, paging, ram

What of the following is the most appropriate scheduling algorithm

Options being-

a. all processes are loaded sequentially 1 by 1

b. load one process at a time and execute processes in RR fashion

c. load 1gb, 1,2gb first then processes 3 and 4 follow

d. All processes can be loaded together and CPU time shared among them

I came across this question somewhere and I was confused, as the answer could b (D) if we consider virtual memory and otherwise (B). Am I missing something here?

Comment: What do you mean by processes of 1gb, 1.2gb, 2gb and 2gb ? Is this the size of the binary executable that represent them ?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, virtual memory should be taken into account here. Its clearly logical. Let me give you the answer by negation.

A.) Clearly not the case as CPU cycles will be wasted.

B.) If we are loading one process at a time, then it doesn't matter what algorithm we are applying afterwards. Its same as #A.

C.) Taking virtual memory into account, if we can load P1 and P2, then for some smaller page size, we can load P3 and P4 too at same time.

D.) As I stated in #C, for an arbitrary smaller page size value, we can load all of them simultaneously and schedule them using Round Robin Scheduling Algorithm.